# Trying to loop through a string, find a certain number, but not finding a duplicate(python)

Tags: python

My problem is, while trying to loop through a string, containing 'cards' i.e- "10D, AC, 8S etc.", I'm searching for a '10', but with my below code, I find the first ten card, but not the second. Why? And can I make my code more efficient?

CODE:

```
import itertools
def best_hand(hand):
    hand = hand.lower()
    for item in hand:
        if "0" in hand:
            zero_index = hand.index("0")
            zero_index = int(zero_index)
        try:
            one_index = zero_index-1
            suit_index = zero_index+1
        except:
            pass
        string_tens = str(hand[one_index]+hand[zero_index]+hand[suit_index].upper())
        print string_tens
    hand = "p"
    list1 = []
    list1.append(hand)    
best_hand("JH QS KC 10D AC 3H 10S" )
```

This code is being written for the 'Seven Card Stud' challenge on Udacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you don't like `re`:

```
>>> a = "KD JC 8D 101 7S 10D 100H AS 10C"
>>> print [i for i in a.split() if i.startswith("10") and i[2].isalpha()]
['10D', '10C']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: How could I apply this technique to find all instances of 'C'?

Comment: Or apply it to find all instances of s, d, h?

Comment: Arguably, that is a different question, although you could start with looking at `i.endswith()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
x="JH QS KC 10D AC 3H 10S"
print [i for i in x.split() if "10" in i]
```

if there can be `100` and you dont want to find it use

```
x="JH QS KC 10D AC 3H 10S"
import re
print [i for i in x.split() if re.findall(r"(?<!\d)10(?!\d)",i)]
```

Comment: I don't understand the second one, can you explain?

Comment: @Sidsy if you want to be sure that `10` should not be a match in `100` we say `(?<!\d)` which a lookbehind stating that before `10` there should not any integer.Same for `(?!\d)` which states after `10` there should not be an interger.

Comment: Hi, can I ask how you would see if part of x ie AC, ends with C using a similar method

Comment: @Sidsy `print [i for i in x.split() if re.findall(r".*C$",i)]` is working for me.Output is `['KC', 'AC']`

Comment: I know why it won't work for me-- what you are using for x, my function takes as an argument.